# Use other than default account in testrpc

Tags: blockchain, testrpc, embark

I am using embark to deploy my contracts.What I need is to call a contract function from a different account rather than account[0] generated by testrpc.
i.e. msg.sender should contain the address of account[1] or account[2] or account[n] where n is less than the number of accounts generated. There should be a way to do so for manual testing purposes in embark console right?

Comment: Have you tried: `MyContract.MyMethod.call({from: accounts[1]});`?
 Assuming you already have your `accounts` array.

Comment: @RomanFrolov Thanks it worked! I just had to use MyContract.MyMethod({from:web3.eth.accounts[1]}) and it also worked by passing address directly. If you copy this in the answer I will accept it as right.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MyContract.MyMethod({ from: accounts[1] });
```

Assuming you already have your accounts array:

```
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
```